# mechanize after login does not redirect to main url

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to login into my stockbroker site using python `mechanize`. I am successfully able to login but `mechanize` does not redirect to the main page.

I want to access the url: `https://secure.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/trading/equity/Trading.asp` 
but `mechanize` stops at url: `https://secure.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/customer/validlogon.asp?nFile=tradehome`

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'https://secure.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/customer/logon.asp'
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
br.open(url)
for form in br.forms():
print form
br.select_form(nr=3)
br.form['FML_USR_ID'] = 'username'
br.form['FML_USR_USR_PSSWRD'] = 'password'
br.form['FML_USR_DT_BRTH'] = 'dateofbirth'
br.submit()
br.geturl()
```

Comment: What if you manually open the main page after log in: `br.open('https://secure.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/trading/equity/Trading.asp')`?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the main page in the same mechanize session after logging in:

```
br.open('https://secure.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/trading/equity/Trading.a‌​sp')
```